# R - RSelenium - Command remoteDriver$sendKeysToActiveElement not working since Chrome Update 76

Tags: google-chrome, r

My Chrome version was recently updated to 76.0.3809.100. After updating the ChromeDriver I noticed that the RSelenium command `...$sendKeysToActiveElement()` function stopped working.

```
> remoteDriver$sendKeysToActiveElement( list(key = 'page_down' ) )
Selenium message:sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-xxxxx', ip: '192.xxx.x.xx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: 'x.x.x_xxx'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: UnknownCommand
     Detail: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I reinstalled Chrome and ChromeDriver 74 and the command worked again. I was wondering if the developers know about this (I have not found a bug report page) and if there is a fix or workaround available?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround

```
 webElem <- remoteDriver$findElement("css", "body")
 webElem$sendKeysToElement( list(key = 'page_down' ) )
```

It seems using the body as Element and sending key inputs to that is still working.

Comment: and i figured out how to report a bug ... https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues